# Getting a JS variable from a website readed with Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Today is my very first day with Python so I´m not even sure if I´m asking in the right way... The thing is that I´m making a python script and I need to read an url and get some info from the result.

I get the info this way:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

fp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://theurliwanttoread")
mybytes = fp.read()
mystr = mybytes.decode("utf8")
fp.close()
parsed = BeautifulSoup(mystr, 'html.parser')
parsedDOM = parsed.prettify())
```

And then, I need to get the price inside the Python script but I don´t know how to parse/deal with it to get it...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice({
        "priceFormat":"a",
        "precision":2,
        "decimalSymbol":".",
        "price": 100
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Would be good if you posted the full response you get. Based on the information here I wrote something that will return the value 1000 from inside { } but of course if the response is more complicated or the position of the value changes that makes my solution less helpful. If this doesn't work please post a full response

mystr = """<script type="text/javascript"> var options = {1000} </script>"""

my_list = mystr.split(" ")
value = my_list[5]
value = value[1:-1]

print value

Comment: mystr value is the whole webpage code so I can´t use split() as I don´t know where that script is gonna be located.

Comment: mystr = """<script type="text/javascript"> var options = {1000} </script>"""
my_list = mystr.split(" ")
options_location = my_list.index('=')
value = my_list[options_location + 1]
value = value[1:-1]
print value

if there's many '=' signs you could use 'options' instead.